# Communication with the service provider failed:null Twitter & android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, signpost

I'm trying to use this code to get the twitter access token in my android application.
The method "provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL)" causes an exception and the log is "communication with the service provider failed:null".

The following code is the class i'm using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Twitter twitter;
    private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "***";
    private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "*******";     

    private static final String REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
    private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
    private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "https://twitter.com";

    private static CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;
    private static CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider;
    //private static OAuthProvider provider;


    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tweet);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {
        askOAuth();

      }
    });
    }
    private void askOAuth() {
        try {
            consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
            provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(REQUEST_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTH_URL);           

            String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
            Toast.makeText(this, authUrl, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        super.onNewIntent(intent);

        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACK_URL)) {

            String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, verifier);
                AccessToken a = new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret());
                twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
                twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.panpan"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permisssion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.panpan.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" 
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="twitter.com" />
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

do provider.retrieveRequestToken in a separate AsyncTask.  That should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem (this ONLY happens on Android 4.X). You can use StrictMode.enableDefaults(); or you can use the next AsyncTask (it's better because it doesn't block the UI Thread).

```
      mAuthTask = new RequestTask();
    mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);// Execute background task
    /**
 * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
 * the user.
 */
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String content;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        httpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        httpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(REQUEST_URL,
                ACCESS_URL, AUTHORIZE_URL);

        try {
            authUrl = httpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(
                    httpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (success == true) {
            Log.e("LoginUsingTwitterActivity", "onPostExecute");
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
    }
}
```